# Help regarding sub figures, works with {subcaption} pakage but not with {subfigure} but both of them cannot come together in template

Tags: subfloats

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
%\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht] 
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Speed_torque_healthyandfaulty.eps}}; 
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (3.7,1.5)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.36\textwidth]{Speed_torque_healthyandfaulty_zoomed.eps}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{torque}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=0.96\textwidth]{Speed_healthyandfaulty.eps}}; 
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (1.8,1.5)
{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Speed_healthyandfaulty_zoomed.eps}}; \end{tikzpicture} \caption{torque!}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{figures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `subfigure`  is considered deprecated. Why don't you want to use `subcaption` instead, since it already seems to work?

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete, it is replaced with `subfig`, which determine `\subfloat` environment. `subcaptin` is considered as more powerful/flexible  than `subfig`. `subfigure` and `subfig` packages are not compatible with `subcaption`.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned in comments:

- `subfigure` is obsolete package. Don't use it! It was replaced with the `\subfig` package.
- `subfigure` environment, defined by `subfigure` package hasn't anything common with environment with the same name defined by `subcaption`
- `subfig` package define environment `subloat` which has the following syntax:

```
\subfloat[<options>][< sub caption>]{sub figure file name}
```

- `subcaption` package is more powerful/flexible package, for example better support `hyperef` referencing etc. SInce you already use it, I don't see any reason to abandon a good solution.

Anyway, using `subfig` package, your MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\subfloat[torque]% <---
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Speed_torque_healthyandfaulty.eps}};
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (3.7,1.5)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{Speed_torque_healthyandfaulty_zoomed.eps}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\hfill
\subfloat[torque!]% <---
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Speed_healthyandfaulty.eps}};
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (1.8,1.5)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Speed_healthyandfaulty_zoomed.eps}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
}
\caption{figures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]